# proper connecting characters or words depending on the length of function arguments given

Tags: php, arrays, loops, arguments

In this simple example that I've created, corresponding connecting characters and words are inserted depending on the length of arguments given to the `showArgs` function. If two arguments are given, the connecting word would be 'and', resulting to the output "one and two". But the third echo had an issue. If there are 3 or more arguments given, it would be connected with a commas and the last element of is supposed to be prefixed with 'and ', resulting to "one, two, and three". My code displayed different, it's only commas: "one, two, three".

```
function showArgs(...$args) {
    $argsArray = [];
    $say = 'Argument(s) => ';

    foreach($args as $arg) {
        array_push($argsArray, $arg);
    }

    if(count($argsArray) == 2) {
        $say .= implode(' and ', $argsArray);
    } elseif(count($argsArray) <= 3) {
        $say .= implode(', ', $argsArray);
    } elseif (count($argsArray) == end($argsArray)) {
        $say .= implode(' and ', end($argsArray));
    }

    return $say;
}

// First echo
echo showArgs('one');

echo "<br>";

// Second echo
echo showArgs('one','two');

echo "<br>";

// Third echo
echo showArgs('one','two','three'); // Supposed to be one, two, and three
```

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last condition does not make sense: You are comparing the number of elements in the array to the last element of the array - a string.

An easy solution for your algorithm would be to implode all elements excluding the last one and add the last one manually.

So something like:

```
if (count($argsArray) === 1) {
    // You can do this directly at the top of your function as well
    return reset($argsArray);    
} else {
    // at least 2 arguments, if 0 arguments can be given, you need to handle this separately
    return implode(', ', array_slice($argsArray, 0, -1)) . ' and ' . end($argsArray);                                             
}
```

Comment: It worked! And it also reduced some lines. Thanks a lot :)